# Code Blocks no ejecuta parte de mi programa pero VisualStudioCode sí

Tags: c, codeblocks

Lo primero quiero aclarar que el lenguaje que estoy usando es C+/-, no C. Que si no me equivoco es un lenguaje desarrollado específicamente por la UNED para las clases y tiene algunas restricciones, pero es casi igual que C.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que tengo que compilar y ejecutar el programa en un entorno de Codeblocks modificado por la UNED para C+/- para que se pueda autocorregir. En un inicio escribí el programa en VisualStudioCode porque estoy más acostumbrada, pero al intentar ejecutarlo en Codeblocks la mitad de código como que lo ignora por completo y no entiendo qué ocurre.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  const int centro = 35;
  const int inicial = 1;
  int nivel;
  int nivel_inf;
  int indice;

  printf("Lado del rombo? ");
  scanf("%d", &nivel);


  for (int altura = inicial; altura <= nivel; altura++) {

    for (int indice = 1; indice <= nivel-altura; indice++) {
      printf(" ");
    }

    printf("@");

    for(int indice = inicial + 1; indice <= altura; indice++) {

       if (indice % 4 == 0) {
            printf(".");
            }

          else if (indice % 4 == 1) {
              printf("@");
          }

          else if (indice % 4 == 2) {
              printf(".");
          }

          else if (indice % 4 == 3) {
              printf("o");
            }
    }

    for(int indice =altura-1; indice >= inicial; indice--) {

      if (indice % 4 == 0) {
            printf(".");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 1) {
                printf("@");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 2) {
                printf(".");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 3) {
                printf("o");
            }
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

  nivel_inf = nivel - 1;
  indice = indice + 1;

  //a partir de aqui no ejecuta
  for (int altura = nivel_inf; altura >= indice; altura--) {

    for (int indice = 0; indice <= nivel_inf-altura; indice++) {
      printf(" ");
    }

    printf("@");

    for(int indice = inicial + 1; indice <= altura; indice++) {

      if (indice % 4 == 0) {
            printf(".");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 1) {
                printf("@");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 2) {
                printf(".");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 3) {
                printf("o");
            }

    }

    for(int indice = altura-1; indice >= inicial; indice--) {

      if (indice % 4 == 0) {
            printf(".");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 1) {
                printf("@");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 2) {
                printf(".");
            }

      else if (indice % 4 == 3) {
                printf("o");
            }

    }

    printf("\n");
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida. Necesitamos más información para poder responderte. ¿Cómo compilas y ejecutas el código en Visual Studio? ¿Cómo lo haces en CodeBlocks? ¿Usas el mismo compilador en ambos? Tu misma dijiste que C+/- es diferente de C. Es entendible que el código en C pueda no funcionar en ese lenguaje y, ¿hay algún lugar en que podamos acceder al lenguaje que estás usando?

Comment: @Mateo La verdad no sabria explicarte como lo compilo, acabo de empezar en C y en programacion en general. Que yo sepa las diferencias son muy pocas (p. e. no se pueden usar operadores de preincremento) y creo que no hay acceso publico al lenguaje. Si sirve, he intentado compilar el codigo en un compilador online y me da igual que en el entorno de codeblocks, asi que asumo que es probelma del codigo no del entorno.

Answer (score 0):

Probé el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##7VRNT8JAEL33V0wwGAiUT7nwpR5NjFcvJmbdbnHNsott8WL469b96EALBSHRxAM97b7ZefN2uvOoTwWRszS94JKKZcBgHCcBV63XqedxmcCccAm1Onx6AFTJOAGDUiaTSMEE@oNRIcAlp5wIHemagIEk/2CisHnmMkSAy4BTNvL0dhFpIKxV7kmgIGACIjV/UddQqZvDMSVSB6tBpQmXlsbCmPRgEKgGT1LHMazjoYqgZgoRkSwjooVlEkeIjCeZxAxoNMxtdWou2am0t8I1pvkuC3GXDfZDbdkNAFaOFvGbitNoCxXrYB8bxYpltbJiwEOj1Z6swhVMJtDZSCkKaqEg/FZebstEzErYuttsWxc5ja23n611Olt/P5vavWuOdbvxrsH@punT3INxkO/nuv4rTT@@4Xtb/jNb7xDbydr6h9gOtxxP6Um1xyy89gXIxgp8dJD1RNhFw8FIcmv/11APfhPu7IlhwQQMZTPLdcPWbhNYkCjhkfYYIO9LDlIBe2N0mZBSw9h4FmJTlINI7k3sekZnxzMM2X/xjfMLPu4FH3INONvG3ze9zDcipvsu9YR5qzQdfNFQkFmc@o9EiG8) y con el parámetro `Wall` obtuve las siguientes advertencias:

```
.code.tio.c:4:13: warning: unused variable 'centro' [-Wunused-variable]
  const int centro = 35;
            ^
.code.tio.c:64:12: warning: variable 'indice' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  indice = indice + 1;
           ^~~~~~
.code.tio.c:8:13: note: initialize the variable 'indice' to silence this warning
  int indice;
            ^
             = 0
```

Ahora el problema está más que claro. La variable `indice` no es inicializada así que contiene un valor indeterminado, produciendo un comportamiento inconsistente.

La solución es darle un valor a esa variable.

Comment: fua muchisimas gracias! que tonteria era y no lo veia, ya va perfecto :)